# Four bars are drawn without replacement from ten bars marked from $1$ to $10$. Find the probability of smallest number being $5$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

A bag contains ten bars marked from $1$ to $10$. Four bars are drawn without replacement, the number noted. Find the probability of:

i. The smallest number is $5$.

ii. The biggest number is $5$.

My Attempt:

i. For the smallest number $5$ $\to$ favorable cases  $5,6,7,8,9,10$ (unordered)

total probability space: $\binom{10}{4}$

Pr(of being smallest number 5): $\dfrac{\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}$

ii. for the biggest number $5$ $\to$ favourable cases is $1,2,3,4,5$ (unordered)

total probability space: $\binom{10}{4}$

pr(of being Biggest number 5): $\dfrac{\binom{5}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}$

I am confused about how do I remove the other possibilities in both cases? For example, the smallest number $5$, how do I exclude the probability of not having $1,2,3,4$?

Comment: Choose the $5$ and three from the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in order for the smallest number to be $5$, you must draw the $5$ and any three of the numbers $6,7,8,9$, and $10$, which can be done in $\binom53=10$ ways. Similarly, in order for the largest number to be $5$, you must draw the $5$ and any three of the numbers $1,2,3$, and $4$, which can be done in $\binom43=4$ ways.

You *can* start with the calculations that you made and subtract the unwanted cases, but that approach is more work than is really necessary. In the first problem, for instance, you get $\binom64$ ways to draw four cards from the set $\{5,6,7,8,9,10\}$. You don’t want the sets of four cards drawn from the set $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$, and there are $\binom54$ of those, so you really have just $\binom64-\binom54=15-5=10$ possibilities. Similarly, in the second program you want to discard the draw of $1,2,3$ and $4$, so instead of $\binom54=5$ possibilities, you have only $\binom54-1=4$ possibilities.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: No, because they are drawn without replacement.

Comment: yes, now I can see why it is a bit lengthy in my approach. Thanks

Comment: @Aurthur: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

What you have computed in i is the chance that the smallest is at least $5$, not that it is exactly $5$ because you have computed the chance that all four are in the range $5$ to $10$.  You need to compute the number of ways you can get $5$ and three out of $6-10$, which is $\frac {1C1 \cdot 5C3}{10C4}$.

You have a similar problem with ii.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, I understood where I was going wrong